# DoCmd multiple where clauses

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have form where user can search the database by worker ID , name/surname, job.
I want to make possible all possible variations e.g. ID+name/surname+job or ID+job, or name/surname etc.
I have done all except combinations with ID's. Searching only by ID works, but combinations don't as I do not know what is the correct syntax. I have tried many, many ways to do this, but with no result.

Here is searching only by ID:

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "DarbiniekiSearchResults", acFormDS
   Forms!DarbiniekiSearchResults.RecordSource = "" _
     & "SELECT * " _
     & "FROM Darbinieks " _
     & "WHERE ID_darbinieks=" & Forms!SearchDarbinieki!darbIDsearch
```

And here is what I am trying to do: ID+job:

```
    DoCmd.OpenForm "DarbiniekiSearchResults", acFormDS
   Forms!DarbiniekiSearchResults.RecordSource = "" _
     & "SELECT * " _
     & "FROM Darbinieks " _
     & "WHERE ID_darbinieks= & Forms!SearchDarbinieki!darbIDsearch OR amats_darb= '" & Forms!SearchDarbinieki!darbAmatsSearch & "'"
```

And the error is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA2bi.png

Comment: If you look closely at the error, you will notice the string for amats_darb begins with a single quote and ends with a double quote.

Comment: @MichaelBlaustein The whole error starts with single quote, then the string for amats_darb begins with single quote, ends with single quote and the whole thing ends with single quote.
I am sure that the problem is in ID_darbinieks=...

Comment: `... & "WHERE ID_darbinieks=" & Forms!SearchDarbinieki!darbIDsearch  & " OR amats_darb= '" & Forms!SearchDarbinieki!darbAmatsSearch & "'"`

Comment: If Tim Enters that as an Answer as opposed to a comment then it can be marked as correct